# Selenium-C#: SendKeys timing out & JS Executor throwing error

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to paste the data(which is quiet big) in the "Textarea1" control, below are the two methods I tried using, but first method tries pasting the data but throws timeout error sometime, and second one throws JS error. please help

```
public StringBuilder PasteDataIn_Tarea1
{
    set
    {
        //Method1
        Textarea1.Clear();
        Textarea1.SendKeys(value.ToString());

        //Method2
        IWebDriver driver; 
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

        StringBuilder javascript = new StringBuilder();
        javascript.Append(string.Format("$('#Textarea1').text('{0}')", value));//value has my data which is quiet big, "Textarea1" is where I need to paste my data
        js.ExecuteScript(javascript.ToString()); // Js exector which should paste my data            
    }
}
```

`Method2` throws below exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: JavaScript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)

I prefer going to `Method2` as the first one takes time to paste the data in the textarea.

Comment: What **exact** exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Added the method2 exception, for the first method it`s the webdriver timeout exception

Comment: IMO, `Method1` is much more cleaner.

Comment: It`s easy to use Method1 but it takes time to paste the data, like character by character it`s pasting, that`s why it`s timing out

Comment: Additionally, you are having `constants` like `InputEle`, else using `IJavaScriptExecutor` would have been more easier with direct `XPath`

Comment: Actually solved this myself using the below code: ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", Textarea1, value.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the browser timeout:

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
 ChromeDriverService svc = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(svc, options,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

The example above takes the command timeout to 5 minutes. I had a similar problem and this is what worked for me.